# Increment a variable whenever onCreate() is called

Tags: java, android

I want to increment the test variable whenever onCreate() is called but my app is crashing. Please help me find out the fix and please tell me why my app is crashing.

```
public int test = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNum);
    new MainActivity().test++;
    num.setText(new MainActivity().test);
}
```

Comment: `test++;
        num.setText(""+test);`

Comment: I think you shouldn't instantiate MainActivity (`new MainActivity()`) like such ways. I recommend to use `SharedPreferences` to record count.

Comment: `onCreate` is only called once per activity *instance*. The instances are created for you by Android framework. You never make instances of activities yourself (no `new MainActivity()`). "Open activity" is not "start application" is not `Activity.onCreate` when working with Android apps.

Comment: I suggest to read about how Activities work and their lifecycle to approach problem correctly: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so let me get you to understand a bit about the activity lifecycle:

**onCreate()**

Is called every time the activity is created, meaning there is really no use for you to increment the test in this method, because it will always be 1.

**onStart()**

Will be called every time the activity is shown, meaning when the activity is created or when you go back to the activity, I think this is the method where you increment test.

**example**

```
public int test = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNum);


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    test++;
    num.setText(String.valueOf(test));


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never create an instance of `Activity` by your self

You can directly access your `test` in your `MainActivity` no need to use `MainActivity().test` to access your `test` variable

if you want to set an `integer` value to your `textview` then you need  to convert your integer into a `string` value like `String.valueOf(test)` or `""+test`

Try this way

```
public int test=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView num=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNum);
    test++;
    num.setText(String.valueOf(test));
}
```

if you want to increment your test variable whenever `onCreate()` called then you can use `SharedPreferences`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String prefName = "MY_PREFS_NAME";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        int test = prefs.getInt("counter", 0);
        test++;
        editor.putInt("counter", test);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does technically answer the question, you should explain why "I want to incremen test variable whenever onCreate() is called" probably won't give them the expected result (i.e. the result will always be `1`).

Comment: @EugenPechanec yes you are right i have updated my answer